# How can I use a Pip module with Quickly?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I'm trying to write an application using Quickly.

I'm writing a new Python 3 file in which I import a module installed via `pip3` (pystache). However, when I go to `quickly package`, I get a traceback error:

```
alex@ubuntu:~/Development/templater$ quickly package
......
----------------------------------
Command returned some ERRORS:
----------------------------------
ERROR: Python module pystache not found
----------------------------------
Do you want to continue (this is not safe!)? y/[n]:
```

How can I ensure that this works, and pystache is picked up by the build system?

At the request of an answer, I've run `which python`, which returns `/usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another version of Python installed?  That is my guess so when you installed the module it was set to work with say Python 2.7.

Type this in the terminal.  I will tell you what python version it recognizes.

```
which python
```

For python3.2 (on my system), it would say `usr/bin/python3.2`.

If you see `usr/bin/python`, then the modules are being synced to python 2.7 or whatever the standard version is installed.

Comment: Is this an attempt to *answer* the question? If so, I recommend expanding this to explain what you're recommending the OP *do*.

Comment: @dustin: i'm trying to use python 3. when i installed the module i used `pip3`, not `pip`. at the top of my custom python script i have `#!/usr/bin/python3`, not `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @strugee the shebang line should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: @dustin i made that change. still getting errors.

Comment: @strugee are you opening a new file and doing import pystache and then getting errors?  You might want to think about asking this question on stackoverflow since it is programming not Ubuntu.

Comment: @dustin yeah, i have a top-level dir called "templater". then in that i have another "templater", so "templater/templater" in which window classes, etc. are. i put a new python 3 file in the "templater/templater" dir, in which i imported pystache.

Comment: @strugee this may seem like a dumb idea have you tried opening the shell and then doing the import to see if it works there?

Comment: @dustin yes: https://gist.github.com/strugee/e9ed7d7b8725bc22c2b2

Comment: Quickly is most likely using Python 2. There is no such thing as a Python 2 or Python 3 file, it's the interpreter that matters. Also, setting the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` doesn't ensure it gets executed with Python 3.

Comment: @timo so what should it be?

Comment: @strugee: it doesn't really matter. The shebang line is only executed when the file is set as executable and run with `./myscript.py`. In any other case, the line is ignored and it doesn't matter what it says, so you can still happily execute a "Python 3" file with Python 2. I was just trying to say that there is no guarantee a file is always run with the correct Python version.

Comment: @Timo okay. I'll ask about this on Stack Overflow; the original question still stands.